# Html.Sitecore().Controller on a CD - No route in the route table matches the supplied values

Tags: configuration, content-delivery, routing

I am having a similar problem to [InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/invalidoperationexception-no-route-in-the-route-table-matches-the-supplied-valu)

That is, I am getting the error:

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values

On a Content Delivery Server because I have disabled Sitecore.Speak.Mvc.config (I have confirmed, if I enable this config, my code works).

My problem is this. The code that is failing is using:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Controller(GlobalControllers.Page.Name, GlobalControllers.Page.Actions.HeadHTML)
```

The above SO thread suggests manually adding the route, as in:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "Bogus-Required-Route",
    "bogus-required-route/{controller}/{action}",
);
```

But I'm not actually calling a route. I'm just feeding the controller name and action, so I would need to add just the basic route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    {controller}/{action}",
);
```

But doesn't that route already exist? If I add if for CDs, won't it blow up on the CM where I have the config enabled? What's the downside to just enabling this config on the CD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the SO answer, the real issue is that without enabling the **Sitecore.Speak.MVC.config**, there's no route pattern matching just `{controller}/{action}`.

The answer that will solve your problem is that you need to enable a config on the Content Delivery Servers that enable this route.

There are a couple ways you can do this:

#### Option 1: Enable Sitecore.Speak.MVC.config

Let's take look at what this config is doing:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeCommandRoute, Sitecore.Speak.Client" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']"/>
      </initialize>
      <mvc.renderPlaceholder>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.RenderAddedContent, Sitecore.Speak.Client"/>
      </mvc.renderPlaceholder>
    </pipelines>
    <mvc>
      <precompilation>
        <assemblies>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Sitecore.Speak.Web" />
        </assemblies>
      </precompilation>
    </mvc>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This config is doing three things:

- Initializing the Command Route (which is really the piece you need)
- Adding a `<renderPlaceholder>` processor that renders added content.
- Adds the Sitecore.Speak.Web assembly to the list of precompiled assemblies.

So, in a nutshell, there isn't much here that will harm a CD if this config is enabled, but the last two points aren't needed by the Content Delivery server.

#### Option 2: Enable Command Route Manually

You can create a patch config that patches in the **InitializeCommandRoute**  processor above to the `<initialize>` pipeline.  If this patch config exists on the CM, where this processor is already defined, it won't conflict.

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeCommandRoute, Sitecore.Speak.Client" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']"/>
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```